# How to print results from text file to window using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, output

I have a text file with a bunch of names and figures that I would like to print to my window. I am using Python 3.3 and Tkinter. So to elaborate I would like the program to read a the text file and then show the contents of the text file in the program (either in label or text area)

So something like:

```
Results = Label(window, text = "HERE I WANT THE RESULTS FROM THE TEXT FILE")
Results.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: How long have you spent on this?

Comment: A good hour going through some material provided by my teacher and browsing Google

Comment: Hint: you actually have two questions. "How do I read a file into a string?" and "how do I put a string into a text area?"

Comment: Okay but could I please get some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments it seems you know how to read a text file:

```
data_file = open("myfile.txt")
data = data_file.read()
data_file.close()
```

And you know how to put a string into a label:

```
Results = Label(window, text = data)
Results.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

So, to put them together, you just... Put them together.

```
file = open("myfile.txt")
data = file.read()
file.close()
Results = Label(window, text = data)
Results.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much unfortunately I can't up vote yet but this was really helpful.

Comment: A label isn't appropriate for data from a file. A better example would use a `Text` widget.

Comment: So replace Label with Text. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do to update a text label after updating:

```
Results.config(text="New Text")
Results.update_idletasks()
```

You can also run the update_idletasks() function against the main Tkinter window object, which will refresh all values that have been updated.

As far as opening a file and reading values from it, check out this page:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/File_IO

Comment: Still don't really understand. I understand how to print labels and text areas and how to read text files. But to have it read to the label is where I am stuck on.

Comment: The config command changes the text in the object to what you specify.  The update_idletasks function tells the Tk window to refresh the window based on what is shown.

Comment: If the program is written properly, `update_idletasks` is pointless, since the screen will update as soon as the event loop is re-entered.

Comment: Thanks, I was using it in particular for a status bar, and had thought that it was necessary.  Glad to be proven wrong on that...brb removing uneccessary code.