# Showing txt file on GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show the txt file on GUI. However, I'm having some problem.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
window=Tk()
window.title("Guild of Ceramic Arts")
def showproductsbt():
    file=open(tab2,"products.txt","r")
tab_control=ttk.Notebook(window)
tab2=ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab2,text="Order Products")
productslist=Label(tab2,text="Products list",font=("",15)).grid(column=0,row=0)
showproducts=Button(tab2,text="Show Products",font=("",10),command=showproductsbt).grid(column=2,row=0)
tab_control.pack(expand=1,fill='both')
window.mainloop()
```

This is the code and it shows this type of error if I press the show product button.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call las`enter code here`t):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Yoon Nam_Python Project\Python System\Python code.py", line 97, in showproductsbt`enter code here`
    file=open(tab2,"products.txt","r")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I tried to get help from other resources but I couldn't really understand much.

Comment: There should not be `tab2` as an argument to `open`.

Comment: I have 3 tabs and tab 2 is for displaying products. If I cannot type in tab2 in the code, how can I define that the txt file would show up on tab2?

Comment: You should learn how to open file in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print results from text file to window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889170/how-to-print-results-from-text-file-to-window-using-python)

Comment: ***"TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"***: Read up on [`open(file, mode='r', ...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for the `open` method is the file's name, not a tkinter frame, and that's the error. I'm not sure what you're trying to do passing `tab2`, but you simply need to remove that, and write `file = open('products.txt', 'r')` which will give you the file handle and then you can do whatever you want with it.

You should probably consider using a context manager:

```
with open('products.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Do something with the file
```

This will automatically close the file when you exit the scope so you don't have to worry about that.